# Using sqlite database to add events to a users calendar.

Tags: android, events, calendar, sqlite

Can anyone please provide a Tutorial or Example of how to use a sqlite database for adding events to the database and in-turn adding them to the users calendar.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Some database tutorial is here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

You can add events into calendar through content provider. But it's available since api level 14. Here is tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

In older android versions you can use intent's to open calendar. It will not insert event into calendar, but will open calendar app and fill some fields. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert

Comment: Hi, The reason I'm not using intent's is because it calls the field entry form before inserting the event, that to me is to long winded for what I need, also using either intent's or the content provider I can not figure out how to add the recurring events in the fashion I need for example using the recurrence rules  I cant get an event recurring in this pattern ( 4days--- 4days gap---- then 4days again) repeated infinitely and all being the same event. So my other idea was to put the event into a database and add then to the calendar from there?